# Passing a timer to a child view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

In my top level view, I have declared a timer like so:

```
Struct ContentView: View  {
    @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: 
     .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                if self.timerMode == .warmup {
                    WarmupView(
                        timer: $timer
                    )
                if self.timerMode == .work {
                    WorkView(
                        timer: $timer
                    )
       }
    }
}
```

In a child view, I want to be able to access and update this timer, which will serve as the single source of truth.

```
Struct WarmupView: View {
  @Binding var timer: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>
  @Binding var timeRemaining: Int

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("\(self.timeRemaining)").font(.system(size: 160))
                            .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                            if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                                self.timeRemaining -= 1
                            }
                        }
    }
  }
}
```

The timer is publishing to the warmup view without issues, but when timerMode is updated to .work (which has nearly identical code) and the view changes, the timer stops publishing.

Comment: It is not clear entire workflow. Would you provide complete demo code?

Answer (score 1):

Simple as changing the type of your `@Binding var timer` in your `WarmupView` to `Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>`. The `.autoconnect()` wraps the timer publisher in another publisher, which changes the type.

---

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View  {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var remaining = 100

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(remaining)")
            .font(.system(size: 160))
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if self.remaining > 0 {
                    self.remaining -= 1
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and the compiler choked "Use of undeclared type 'Publishers'"

Comment: Are you importing Combine?

Comment: I imported combine and now the timer is being passed successfully.  However, the timer stops firing when the view changes to another view that is passed the same timer instance.  How do I keep the timer persisting across views?

Comment: What do you mean by “the view changing to another view”?

Comment: I just updated my post to explain a bit more clearly.

Comment: Repo here if you want to take a closer look: https://github.com/wileybaba/interval-timer/tree/master/Interval%20Timer

Comment: Without having a detailed look at your code, it might be something related to the Publisher being Connectable. Try calling `.connect()` on the Publisher in the WorkView. I’ll have a closer look later today.

Comment: I ended up just reinstantiating the timer in each view and setting up start/stop logic in each view as well.